# Is this relation can be possible(phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to do this??

table1 has a column name 'id'
table2 has a column name 'id' too.

because table2 accepts multiple value from selected checkbox, and I want to relate it with table1. table1 contains the firstname lastname and etc. while table2 contains selected value from the checkbox (1 or more selected).

**table1**

```
id  |   firstname   |  lastname

1   |   John        |   Conner
```

**table2**

```
id   |  sports

1    |  basketball

2    |  volleyball

3    |  tennis
```

*john selected 3 values from the checkboxes...*

how can I relate or make it that the first inserted data will own the 3 values or will be displayed like this:

```
id  |  firstname   |   lastname   |   sports

1   |   John       |   Conner     |   basketball
```

|  volleyball -------->

|  tennis------------->

thanks in advance...
sorry for the illustrations.

Comment: Hint: Phpmyadmin is only a tool to interact with the database. It is not *the* database.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'll need a [Many to Many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

You'll need a third table that keeps the relationships between the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3rd table that connects users to sports.

```
connections
--------------------------
id | users_id  | sports_id
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 1         | 2
3  | 2         | 1
--------------------------
```

The above table would connect user #1 to sports #1 and #2, user #2 to sport #1. (I renamed the tables from your question to make my example more readable: table1 -> users and table2 -> sports)

To combine the records using this method, you can call

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, sports.sports
FROM connections
JOIN users ON connections.users_id = users.id
JOIN sports ON connections.sports_id = sports.id
```

This also ables you to show users that have selected specific sport from the list. This way you can also edit sports name once to affect all results at the same time.

- Good examples of [JOIN, OUTER JOIN and LEFT JOIN on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

## Working example using PHP/MySQLi

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database'); // Database connection
if ($db->connect_errno > 0) { // Do we have a connection?
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
// Set the sql query
$sql = "SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, sports.sports
    FROM connections
    JOIN users ON connections.users_id = users.id
    JOIN sports ON connections.sports_id = sports.id";

if (! ($result = $db->query($sql))) { // Run the query, get results to $result, if errors die
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) { // Loop through the results and echo
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' likes ' . $row['sports'] . '<br />';
    // To see all $row variables in nice format we can do: echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

I added Kyle Reese as user id #2, so the output from my query results would be:

```
John Conner likes basketball
John Conner likes volleyball
Kyle Reese likes basketball
```

- [Read more about MySQLi (php.net)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php)
- [Example adapted from 'MySQLi for Beginners' (codular.com)](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: I don't know where to put the SELECT statement... I tried it in your connections table.. still nothing happened

Comment: I added a working example to my answer, I hope it'll help you and others reading this.